# What Does '6k views' mean and how can I format the number in PHP

Tags: php

What does "6k views" mean and how can I format this number in PHP?

Comment: *(related)* http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SI_prefix

Answer (score 26, accepted):

*k* is the abbreviation for the [Kilo prefix](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kilo-) and means thousand. So 6k means six thousand.

You can format a number in such a way with the following function using division:

```
function format($number) {
    $prefixes = 'kMGTPEZY';
    if ($number >= 1000) {
        for ($i=-1; $number>=1000; ++$i) {
            $number /= 1000;
        }
        return floor($number).$prefixes[$i];
    }
    return $number;
}
```

Or using logarithm base 10 and exponentiation:

```
function format($number) {
    $prefixes = 'kMGTPEZY';
    if ($number >= 1000) {
        $log1000 = floor(log10($number)/3);
        return floor($number/pow(1000, $log1000)).$prefixes[$log1000-1];
    }
    return $number;
}
```

Comment: Actually it gives `1k 10k 100k 500M 500M 50000M 333333G` for `array(1000, 10000, 100000, 1000000, 1000000, 100000000, 1000000000);`

Answer (score 11):

'6k views' on StackOverflow refers to the number of views a question has received. It means 6000 views.

If you're looking to format a similar style number in php then try something like

```
$number = "";
if( $value > 1000 )
{
    $number .= floor($value / 1000) . "k";
} else {
    $number .= $value;
}
echo $number . " views".
```

Obviously you can add cases for m, g and t views if desired.

Comment: Thanks, don't forget Gumbo's answer though. It's clearly more generic, if a little more cryptic for the uninitiated.

Answer (score 8):

Abridged from http://tamlyn.org/2008/12/formatting-bytes-with-significant-figures-in-php/

```
/** Calculate $value to $sigFigs significant figures */
function sigFig($value, $sigFigs = 3) {
    //convert to scientific notation e.g. 12345 -> 1.2345x10^4
    //where $significand is 1.2345 and $exponent is 4
    $exponent = floor(log10(abs($value))+1);
    $significand = round(($value
        / pow(10, $exponent))
        * pow(10, $sigFigs))
        / pow(10, $sigFigs);
    return $significand * pow(10, $exponent);
}

/** Format $value with the appropriate SI prefix symbol */
function format($value, $sigFigs = 3)
{
    //SI prefix symbols
    $units = array('', 'k', 'M', 'G', 'T', 'P', 'E');
    //how many powers of 1000 in the value?
    $index = floor(log10($value)/3);
    $value = $index ? $value/pow(1000, $index) : $value;
    return sigFig($value, $sigFigs) . $units[$index];
}
```

Doing `*11` because `*10` is too obvious

```
for($number = 100; $number < 100000000000000000000; $number*=11) {
   echo format($number), PHP_EOL;
}
```

gives

```
100 1.1k 12.1k 133k 1.46M 16.1M 177M 1.95G 21.4G 236G 2.59T 28.5T 314T 3.45P 38P 418P 4.59E 50.5E
```

If you need the decimals, use the above, else Gumbo's solution is more compact. Gives:

```
100 1k 12k 133k 1M 16M 177M 1G 21G 235G 2T 28T 313T 3P 37P 417P 4E 50E
```

Answer (score 3):

```
$number="6000";
$val=($number/1000)."k";
//= 6k
```

or if the `$number="6k";`

```
echo str_replace("k","000",$number);
```

Answer (score 2):

In `6k`, the `k` means `kilo` (i hope you know) which equals to `6000`. You replace the thousand figure with `k`, that's it. Hope that helps :)

Comment: is kilo mean kilo gram or kilo meter

Comment: @moustafa: hmmm :) meter and gram are different units, just concentrate on **kilo** part.

Comment: kilo means 1000 just like mili means 0,001

Comment: @moustafa, just kilo. In this case would be kilo - views => 6,000 views

Answer (score 2):

1. k means 1000, so '6k views' = 6000 views.
2. normally, on every access to a page, a counter in a database is increased by 1. This just gets queried on every page access and printed.
3. after you queried the value, divide it by 1000 and add a 'k' to the number (if the number is > 1000).

Answer (score 0):

```
function sigFig($value, $sigFigs = 3) {
    setlocale(LC_ALL, 'it_IT@euro', 'it_IT', 'it'); 
    $exponent = floor(log10(abs($value))+1);
    $significand = round(($value
        / pow(10, $exponent))
        * pow(10, $sigFigs))
        / pow(10, $sigFigs);
    return $significand * pow(10, $exponent);
}

function format($value, $sigFigs = 3)
{
    $numero = $value;

    if ($numero > 9999) {

      $units = array('', 'k', 'M', 'G', 'T', 'P', 'E');

      $index = floor(log10($value)/3);
      $value = $index ? $value/pow(1000, $index) : $value;
      return sigFig($value, $sigFigs) . $units[$index];
    }else{
      return number_format($numero, 0, '', '.'); ;
    }

    //Resultados:
      //9999 -> 9.999 views
      //10000 -> 10k views
      //10200 -> 10,2k views
}
```