# Php check size of remote folder

Tags: php, ftp, server

I have a user folder on remote server (other than page files). I need check a size of whole "example" folder, not one file. I think i should do it with use a ftp, but I can't.

I have something like this but not working:

```
function dirFTPSize($ftpStream, $dir) {
$size = 0;
$files = ftp_nlist($ftpStream, $dir);

foreach ($files as $remoteFile) {
    if(preg_match('/.*\/\.\.$/', $remoteFile) || preg_match('/.*\/\.$/', $remoteFile)){
        continue;
    }
    $sizeTemp = ftp_size($ftpStream, $remoteFile);
    if ($sizeTemp > 0) {
        $size += $sizeTemp;
    }elseif($sizeTemp == -1){//directorio
        $size += dirFTPSize($ftpStream, $remoteFile);
    }
}

return $size;
}

$hostname = '127.0.0.1';
$username = 'username';
$password = 'password';
$startdir = '/public_html'; // absolute path
$files = array();
$ftpStream = ftp_connect($hostname);
$login = ftp_login($ftpStream, $username, $password);
if (!$ftpStream) {
echo 'Wrong server!';
exit;
} else if (!$login) {
echo 'Wrong username/password!';
exit;
} else {
$size = dirFTPSize($ftpStream, $startdir);
}
echo number_format(($size / 1024 / 1024), 2, '.', '') . ' MB';
ftp_close($ftpStream);
```

Whole time script displays 0.00 MB, what can I do to fix it?

Comment: check this  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/478121/php-get-directory-size

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2788002/i-want-get-the-sum-of-files-size-in-folder-by-php

Comment: Right, but I need connect to another hosting server. I edit my question I add a php code

Comment: Do you have SSH access on the remote server?

Comment: Yes, I've access to SSH console on the remote server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your comments you indicated you have SSH access on the remote server. Great!

Here is a way to use SSH:

```
//connect to remote server (hostname, port)
$connection = ssh2_connect('www.example.com', 22);

//authenticate
ssh2_auth_password($connection, 'username', 'password');

//execute remote command (replace /path/to/directory with absolute path)
$stream = ssh2_exec($connection, 'du -s /path/to/directory');
stream_set_blocking($stream, true);

//get the output
$dirSize = stream_get_contents($stream);

//show the output and close the connection
echo $dirSize;
fclose($stream);
```

This will echo 123456 /path/to/directory where 123456 is the calculated size of the directory's contents. If you need human readable, you could use 'du -ch /path/to/directory | grep total' as the command, this will output formatted (k, M or G).

If you get an error "undefined function ssh2_connect()" you need to install/enable PHP ssh2 module on your local machine

Another way, without SSH could be to run the command on the remote machine.
Create a new file on the remote server, e.g. called 'dirsize.php' with the following code:

```
<?php
$path   = '/path/to/directory';
$output =  exec('du -s ' . $path);
echo trim(str_replace($path, '', $output));
```

(or any other PHP code that can determine the size of a local directory's contents)

And on your local machine include in your code:

```
$dirsize = file_get_contents('http://www.example.com/dirsize.php');
```

Comment: Thanks, is it the other way do it (without ssh2)?

Comment: Can you run php scripts on the remote server?

Comment: Yes, I've access to both servers (admin panel and ftp).

Comment: Unfortunately, "exec() was disabled for security", but I changed script, used using file_get_contents() and my another functions and it's work.

Comment: Of course any PHP code that can determine the size of a local directory's content will work in the second option. I've edited the answer to make that more clear.

Comment: If my answer works for you, please mark it as correct, so it gets the green check mark for future users with the same problem, thanks :-)