# How to count size of folders included subfolders in PHP?

Tags: php

I want to calculate the size of a folder with all the sub-folders included. I know I have to do something with `RecursiveDirectoryIterator`, but it does not count the size of the folder including the sub-folders.

This is my root directory:

```
$MainDir = 'uploads/sfm/'.$UserID;
```

This is how I try to count the size of all files together, included the files in the sub-folders:

```
if (is_dir($MainDir)) { 
    $SumStorage = 0;
    foreach (new RecursiveDirectoryIterator($MainDir) as $file) {
        if ($file->isFile()) {
            $SumStorage += $file->getSize();
        }
    }

    $UsedStorage = $SumStorage/$LimitStorage*100;    
}
```

But it does not count the total size of all the files.

What is going wrong?

Comment: already find the solution her: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2788002/i-want-get-the-sum-of-files-size-in-folder-by-php

Comment: or some thing like: [php get directory size](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/478121/php-get-directory-size)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [i want get the sum of files size in folder by php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2788002/i-want-get-the-sum-of-files-size-in-folder-by-php)