# Display 1000 as 1k using PHP

Tags: php, wordpress

I have beginners skills with PHP and hence need your help guys.

What i am trying to achieve is to round up a number for total shares count for a plugin.

```
my variable is $totalshare
i am using return $totalshare to dispaly the results
```

i would like to achieve results as following example:

```
1000 = 1k
1.230 = 1.2k
1489 = 1.5k
1.660 = 1.6k
.
.
.
15576 = 15.6k
.
.
1201200 = 12.02mil
1211200 = 12.12mil
```

Any help would be much appreciated.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: possible duplicate of [PHP Count round thousand to a K style count like facebook Share . . . Twitter Button ect](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4116499/php-count-round-thousand-to-a-k-style-count-like-facebook-share-twitter-bu)

Comment: or http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16292304/php-count-round-thousand-to-a-k-style-count-facebook-share

Comment: those answers does not round up to two decimal places, and iv tried them before posting this question, did not work.

Comment: or http://stackoverflow.com/a/2704122/2097224

Comment: The principal question is here: What have you tried? SO is not a platform for getting things done your homework.

Answer (score 0):

Simplest way:

```
if($n>=1000) $n = ($n/1000)."k";
```

if you want something more i can edit

Answer (score 0):

You can write like this,

```
function convertShares($shareValue){
    if($shareValue < 1000){
    return shareValue;
    }elseif($shareValue > 100000 ){
          return number_format($shareValue/100000,2) . "mil";
    }else{
        return number_format($shareValue/1000,2) . "k";
    }
  }
```